# Add Label to prometheus Histogram After Starting the timer

Tags: java, timer, prometheus

I want to have user login stats using Histograms on Prometheus.

I create a timer when I enter the login method, and observe the duration at the end of the method, this is very simple and nice.

What I miss is that, I want to label this measurement *after* starting the timer. For example:

- I want to label with login_failed/login_success
- I want to label with the organization users logging in to ( multi-tenancy)

Using simple java client, I could not figure out how to achieve this.

First of all, I need to know if my design is flawed here, as I am fairly new to Prometheus.

Second, is there a way to achieve this task?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> I want to label with login_failed/login_success

This is not recommended, track total attempts and failures instead as two separate metrics. It's easier to work with when calculating ratios.

> Second, is there a way to achieve this task?

Have a look at https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/SimpleTimer.java